# Why does my subscribe never complete?

Tags: android, rx-java, netflix

I am trying to learn about rxJava and reactive programming in context of android and I feel I am nearly there, I just can't quite grasp the complete picture to fully understand what I am doing.

I have the below code which gets a list of instances of a class called iApps from the database

```
 myHelper m = new myHelper(getApplication());
        m.getApps()
                .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .subscribe(currentApps::addAll,
                        throwable -> Log.e("Error Observable", throwable.toString() + " " + Arrays.toString(throwable.getStackTrace())),
                        () -> compareLists(availableApps, currentApps));
}
```

Which uses the following methods:
//From my database caller function

```
public  Callable<ArrayList<iApp>> getApps()
    {
        return this::getCurrentInfo;
    }
```

A custom helper function

```
public class myHelper {

    Context ctx;
    tQuery t;
    public myHelper(Context _ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = _ctx;
        t = new tQuery(_ctx);
    }

    Observable<ArrayList<iApp>> getApps()
    {
        return makeObservable(t.getApps())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
    }

    private static <T> Observable<T> makeObservable(final Callable<T> func) {
        return Observable.create(
                new Observable.OnSubscribe<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
                        try {
                            subscriber.onNext(func.call());

                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            subscriber.onError(ex);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

However my on complete never runs. I have checked the onNext by looping through the results of iApp and outputting one of the fields so I can see that the data is being collected, however my compareLists function is never run.

Could someone explain my oversight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that was embarassing!

```
private static <T> Observable<T> makeObservable(final Callable<T> func) {
        return Observable.create(
                new Observable.OnSubscribe<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
                        try {
                            subscriber.onNext(func.call());
                            subscriber.onCompleted();

                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            subscriber.onError(ex);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```